# Win 8 - how to prepare an image so it does not run through setup?

Tags: hyper-v, image, sysprep, windows-8

I am preparing a Win8 image to use as base for automatic deployments in Hyper-V at the moment.

It seems that whenever a sysprepped image starts, it is running through the whole setup routine - which is bad, as it means setting up a setup user etc.

Can anyone answer or point me to documentation how to avoid this? What I would like is the setup image to:
* Have a predefined active administrative account
* THAT IS IT ;)

The admin account can then be used to join it to a domain (we have some, and some machines outside) as well as give some domain user local rights. I am totally OK with this account being THE administrator account, as well as it being a setup account, but it has to be pre-configured and I would love to avoid the stupid movie every time I set up a vm ;)

Was easier with windows 7 ;)

Comment: are you adding the /OOBE command when SysPreping? Not familiar with SysPrep for Win8 but can't imagine that it's changed much since Win7.

Answer (score 1):

I would use MDT to create a unattend.xml prior to sysprep, the actions you require can all be customised using this method. Auto-logon, domain-join. etc. etc.